# outook add-in in IOS

Tags: android, ios, sharepoint, outlook

Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId is differ in IOS

Hello,
I have developed an outlook add-in to save an email to SharePoint list. Which were working fine in web, client, IOS, and android properly. To save an email to SharePoint i read the email using EWS. From few days I notice the add-in is not working properly for IOS. I debug code and found when I request in my service to read email  Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId is returning wrong formated id which is not matching with web or client id. To read the email I invoked EWS service EmailMessage.Bind which throws "This protocol does not support ImmutableIds". 
Some body help me how can i get the proper id in IOS from office context i have tried Office.context.mailbox.convertToEwsId which does not help.

Samaresh

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

EWS is an older protocol that do not support all the new capabilities of Outlook. Immutable Id is a new property introduced and is not accepted by EWS. The guidance is to use REST API instead of EWS calls as REST API supports immutableID?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes i know i can read the mail details using outlook rest or Graph API with immutable Id. But in my add-in there is a functionality save selected mail to sharepoint as .eml file. REST API return mu json object not mail stream. Can you give me idea, how can i save email to sgharepoint using REST API?

Comment: There is a preview API for getting Mime : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message